# I need only top 20 highest review count among all the cars bar graph?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset, visualization

Basically i have a dataset with car models and i need a bar graph where the highest review count of 20 car brands should be displayed in the bar graph!

I have tried this below code but i am getting all the brand models from the dataset but i need only top 20 highest review count car brands in bar graph.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHZRz.png)]

Used Dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tr1gg3rtrash/cars-2022-dataset?group=owned

Comment: copy the code into the question

Comment: #Data.plot.bar()
plt.figure(figsize=(30,9))
x_zoom = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
y_zoom = np.sin(x_zoom)
plt.bar(Data['car_name'], Data['reviews_count'])
plt.xlabel("car name")
plt.ylabel("Review Count")
plt.show()

Comment: Do you need some more information?

Comment: You need to sort the dataframe by reviews_count using `value_count` then you can slice your dataframe to only work with 20 samples

Answer (score 0):

Pandas contain a feature to sort values for a DataFrame e.g.: `DataFrame.sort_values(<column_name>, ascending=False)`.
For more information on sorting values using pandas can be found in [pandas.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) documentation.

Sorting:

```
Data=Data.sort_values('reviews_count', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Slicing the DataFrame to 20:

```
Data = Data[0:20]
```

Overall:

```
Data=pd.read_csv("CARS_1.csv")
Data=Data.sort_values('reviews_count', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

Data = Data[0:20]

#Data.plot.bar() 
plt.figure(figsize=(30,9)) 
x_zoom = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50) 
y_zoom = np.sin(x_zoom) 
plt.bar(Data['car_name'], Data['reviews_count']) 
plt.xlabel("car name") 
plt.ylabel("Review Count") 
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: [Robo_getit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20570476/robo-getit) was above able to resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sort the dataframe
df.sort_values(['reviews_count', 'car_name',], ascending=False, inplace=True)


plt.figure(figsize=(30,9))
x_zoom = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
y_zoom = np.sin(x_zoom)

plt.bar(df['car_name'][:20], df['reviews_count'][:20])

plt.xlabel("car name")
plt.ylabel("Review Count")
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)

plt.show()
```

[image]